# How to disable Glimpse on a root iFrame document in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, glimpse

I'm attempting to use Glimpse with a site that uses iFrames, and the main layout file is like this:

```
<body>
 <iframe id="mainFrame" width="100%" src="/home/welcome">
    @RenderBody()
 </iframe>
 <iframe id="sidebar" class="ui-layout-west" src ="/sidebar"></iframe>
</body>
```

So Glimpse will load for the main document, then load into both of the iFrames, and the mainFrame Glimpse UI sits on top of the main document Glimpse UI.

I've tried a couple variations of

> ```
> <runtimePolicies>
>     <uris>
>         <add regex="\/"/>
>     </uris>
> </runtimePolicies>
> ```

But anything that catches the main document seems to catch all of the requests.
Any idea how to disable the UI for just the / request?

Answer (score 0):

try using the `^` and `$` respectively at the beginning and the end of your regex as in

```
 <runtimePolicies>
     <uris>
         <add regex="^\/$"/>
     </uris>
 </runtimePolicies>
```

that way you will not match the others starting with `/`

Comment: So it looks like it's matching against the full uri, so ^\/$ won't work either.

Comment: yes, it is matching against the full request uri. Isn't it an option to add your domain to the regex as well? Or anything that might uniquely identify your main page?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up adding

```
$('.glimpse-inline').hide();
```

to the main layout file, as I already had jquery running. Glimpse appears to match against the full url in the runtimePolicies, so I'd need to setup a custom runtimePolicy to get at the uri.AbsolutePath to match against /

Comment: We will have to look at this edge case moving forward and see what we can do.